# every uniformly continuous semigroup of operators can be extended to a uniformly continuous group

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis, analysis, uniform-continuity

I'm reading Vrabie and I'm in trouble with this remark.

---

Given a uniformly continuous semigroup $\{S(t)\mid t\geq 0\}$, since $S(t)$ is invertible and can be extended to a uniformly continuous group via $G:X\longrightarrow  X$ given by\begin{equation*}
 G(t)=
\begin{cases}
\left[S(-t)\right]^{-1} & \text{if}\; t<0 \\
S(t) & \text{if}\; t\geq 0
\end{cases}
\end{equation*}.

---

To see that is a uniformly continuous group we have to check:

1. $G(0)=I$
2. $\displaystyle\lim_{t\to 0} G(t)=I$
3. $G(s+t)=G(s)G(t)$

---

1. $G(0)=S(0)=I$
2. $\displaystyle\lim_{t\to 0^-} G(t)=\displaystyle\lim_{t\to 0^-} [S(-t)]^{-1}=I=S(0)=\displaystyle\lim_{t\to 0^+} G(t)$ since $S(t)$ is invertible .
3. If $s,t\geq 0$ then $$G(s+t)=S(s+t)=S(s)S(t)=G(s)G(t)$$
   If If $s,t\leq 0$ then $$G(s+t)=[S(-s+(-t))]^{-1}=[S(-s)S(-t)]^{-1}=S(-t)^{-1}S(-s)^{-1}=G(t)G(s)$$
   If $t\geq 0$ and $s<0$ with $t+s\geq 0$
   $$G(s+t)=S(s+t)$$ but since $t<0$ I can't write $S(s+t)=S(s)S(t)$. And I can't prove 3.

Comment: Hint : $S(-s)S(t+s)=S(t)$ . Rewrite this using $G(s)$ and $G(t)$.

Comment: $S(-s)=[G(s)]^{-1}$ since $s<0$, $S(t+s)=G(t+s)$ since $t+s\geq 0$ and $S(t)=G(t)$ since $t\geq 0$. Thus, $[G(s)]^{-1}G(t+s)=S(-s)S(t+s)=S(t)=G(t)\iff G(t+s)=G(s)G(t)$. Thanks!!!